# How to create a Facebook account without a phone number or government-issued ID?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to a Facebook account without a phone number or government-issued ID?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. You can create a Facebook account without a phone number or government ID.

Adding a phone number make it more secure and real. There is less chances to get blocked from Facebook and easy to recover your account.

And government ID is only require when Facebook don't believe that you are real. That time you need to send a valid ID proof to Facebook.